# How to reload entirely a page when using pushstate + ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, pushstate, html5-history

I have a problem with my website.

I try to make a full ajax section.

When an user click on a link, the content is loaded by ajax :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET'
}).done(function (data) {
  $('#content_store').html(data);
})
```

The data returned is only the content of a div which I want to update.

If we go directly to the browser on the URL, all the content of the web page is loaded (with headers and footer).

This part is managed by `twig`.

The target URL is added to the user history thank to `pushState`.

The problem I met is that when a user goes back to the URL, the only thing he sees is the content of the `div` and not all the page.

It seems that the result of the ajax request replaced the full web page.

How to force a load of all the contents of the page ?

Comment: Could we see your html just to be sure that isn't the problem ?

Comment: The code is pretty long. I don't think it comes from the html. There is only one div with id "content_store". It's as if the browser associate the response of the ajax call with the url (whose are the same in the browser history and ajax call). I don't meet the problem with Firefox but only with Google Chrome.